# How to research publishers by subject

Tags: publisher, reviews

I'm trying to find a place that not only lists publishers by subject (I know that publishersglobal.com does that) but where I may also find author reviews of the publishers. I am writing a book on a specialized topic and I know the top couple of publishers in that area, but the biggest name has a reputation of not treating its authors very well. As a result, I want to find out more about what other publishers are out there but also have an idea if I actually want to work with them. I'd like to submit the manuscript to a company that is less likely to make me tear my hair out. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't want to answer the question as not enough knowledge, but have you read https://www.sfwa.org/other-resources/for-authors/writer-beware/thumbs-down-publishers/  . The website has other usefull tips and contacts, worth a read.

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck Thanks! That looks really useful. I don't know that the publishers in my topic would be listed there, but it looks like a lot of great information in general. I will check it out in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the user reviews but a very good source of publishers is the Writer's Market (by Writer's Digest).  There is also a version just for fiction.

The publishers are in alphabetical order but there is an index in the back where they are arranged by subject.  The listings aren't just contact info; they often give valuable feedback about how you might fit in.

While there are no reviews per say, if you narrow down your search to a handful, you may turn up reviews (or tales of woe) on internet searches or by asking on appropriate venues.

Tip: The latest WM will be in the reference section of your library.  My library also has it as an e-book (via Hoopla).  I was able to pop it on to my computer for free and screenshot a couple interesting listings (the version on your computer or tablet will disappear after a couple of weeks, though you can check it out again).

I know this isn't what you're looking for but I think you'll have to combine various resources to find your answers.

Comment: In the case of the book I'm working on, it would be non-fiction. I've used the Writer's Market for fiction and poetry before, but not non-fiction. I will have to look into it. Should have come up with that one myself. Thanks!